# how to reference a variable from the parent object in javascript

Tags: javascript, image, canvas

I am trying to write a simple sprite object that will add itself to the canvas when it is initialised:

```
function Sprite(source){
this.x = 100;
this.y = 100;
this.img = new Image();
this.img.src = source;
this.img.onload = function(e){
    context.drawImage(this.img, this.x, this.y);
    };
}//end of object Sprite
```

This does not work as drawImage needs to access the variables outside of the onload handler. How can i access the variables inside my Sprite object from inside the event handler?

Comment: By the way you should not rely on a global `context` object. You should inject the context dependency into the `Sprite` instance if it has to draw itself. `Sprite(source, context)` and the use `this.context`, it's far more flexible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare a variable :

```
function Sprite(source){
  var sprite = this;
  this.x = 100;
  this.y = 100;
  this.img = new Image();
  this.img.src = source;
  this.img.onload = function(e){
    context.drawImage(this, sprite.x, sprite.y);
  };
}//end of object Sprite
```

or [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) your function (I wouldn't do that here as `onload` event handlers are expected to be bound to the related image ) :

```
function Sprite(source){
  this.x = 100;
  this.y = 100;
  this.img = new Image();
  this.img.src = source;
  this.img.onload = (function(e){
    context.drawImage(this.img, this.x, this.y);
  }).bind(this);
}//end of object Sprite
```

Comment: Why your `bind` form is so complex... `context.drawImage.bind(context, this.img, this.x, this.y);`

Comment: @plalx I don't see how that would help. The problem is the binding of the event handler.

Comment: The only operation in the handler is to draw the image. `this.img.onload = context.drawImage.bind(context, this.img, this.x, this.y);`

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean. So yes, supposing there's nothing more in the onload event handler, that would be a solution too. But if x or y changes, the new values wouldn't be used.

Comment: Hum yeah, that might be a problem ;) It also requires less refactoring if you ever want to add operations. Sold! However, I added something in the comments but perhaps you should as well say on word on injecting the `context` dependency into the `Sprite` instance rather than relying on a global variable.

Comment: I saw (and upvoted) your comment. I think it's not related enough, it's better to be just a comment. This being said, your alternate way of binding is worth of another answer (limits being specified).

Comment: Well in this case I just prefer using a closure. It's quite faster than `bind`, which has to perform arguments slicing and other things.